# startActivityForResult() e onActivityResult() em Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragment

Eu tenho uma `MainActivity` que me permite abrir dois `Fragments`. A classe `Fragment_1` possui um `Button` que no seu `Listener` abre uma segunda atividade através da seguinte chamada:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SegundaActivity.class);
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

O meu problema é que na classe `Fragment_1` não consigo capturar a `Intent` de resposta através do método `onActivityResult()`:

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1) {
String resposta = data.getStringExtra("resposta");}
```

Na classe `SegundaActivity`, a resposta é enviada da seguinte forma:

```
Intent devolve = new Intent();
devolve.putExtra("resposta", "Resposta");
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, devolve);
finish();
```

Comment: Olá ramaral, enquanto aguardava por respostas descobri qual era o meu problema: Eu não podia abrir a classe SegundaActivity através da chamada "getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 1)", ou seja, se eu adicionar o método "getActivity()" ao método "startActivityForResult()" não vou conseguir receber a Intent de resposta!! Contudo não vou deixar de ler o que me enviou. Obrigado.

Comment: Os links que enviei nada têm haver com a sua questão, por isso é que apaguei o comentário.

Comment: Ok. Contudo envio o seguinte link que me ajudou na resolução do meu problema: http://helpdev.com.br/2014/03/31/android-chamando-o-onactivityresult-em-fragment-onactivityresult-not-called-in-fragment/

Comment: Só isso resolveu? Por aquilo que estive a ler, não basta chamar `startActivityForResult(intent, 1)` sem `getActivity()`. Na *activity* que hospeda o *fragmento* deverá ser feito o *overrride* do método `startActivityForResult()` e chamar `super.startActivityForResult()`.

Comment: ramaral, comigo resolveu... Já agora, quando você diz override do método startActivityForResult() não queria dizer antes override do método onActivityResult() e chamar super.onActivityResult()? Se sim, eu já possuía isso...

Comment: Sim tem razão: *override do método `onActivityResult()` e chamar `super.onActivityResult()`*

Comment: Já que consegui encontrar a solução, você podia postar uma resposta.

Comment: Não ficou claro o que você está perguntando. Favor reformular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exemplo da solução para o meu problema:

**Classe Fragment_1:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    botao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SegundaActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }

    });
    ...
    return viewlayout;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1) {
        String resposta = data.getStringExtra("resposta");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Mensagem Recebida da SegundaActivity:\n" + resposta, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**SegundaActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_segunda);

    Button botao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);     
    botao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent devolve = new Intent();
        devolve.putExtra("resposta", "Resposta");
        setResult(RESULT_OK, devolve);
        finish();               
    });     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sei que o tópico já é antigo mas passei pelo mesmo problema e estou usando Kotlin.

No meu caso tive que adicionar `super.` na frente do `startActivityForResult` No meu caso é uma requisição bluetooth, mas pode ser usada em outros exemplos:

**Fragment.kt**

```
//Dentro da classe do Fragment
val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
private var REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1

//Dentro de OnCreateView
if (bluetoothAdapter?.isEnabled == false{
    val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
    super.startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)
}

//Logo depois
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    when (requestCode){
        REQUEST_ENABLE_BT -> {
            when (resultCode) {
                Activity.RESULT_CANCELED -> {
                    //Solicitação recusada
                }
                Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
                    //Solicitação aceita
                }
            }
        }
```